# label not vertically aligned with text box in IE6

Tags: html, css

Hi I have labels beside text boxes in my application. They are contained within a table. In IE6 the labels always appear slightly higher than the textboxes.

Can someone please tell me how to style to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the way to style this is to put vertical-align: middle on all of the inline elements in that line.

That is, the text box as well as the label beside it, not just one or the other.

Whether that fixes this particular issue on IE6 though is anyone's guess.  If you continue to have problems you may want to upload an example.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- [Try adding reset CSS to your style sheet on top before anything](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)
- Use [universal-ie6-css](http://code.google.com/p/universal-ie6-css/)
- See [Developing CSS for IE6 and 7](http://www.edgeofmyseat.com/blog/developing-css-for-ie6-and-7)